# trying to simultaneously compile three template .cpp files causes "error: redefinition of method"

Tags: c++, linux, templates, header, linker

I have a project for university that I managed to get working using my own makefile/terminal command. BUT I get zero marks on the university's auto marker. I THINK this is because they use a makefile that tries to execute all three cpp files in one line with the compiler(if that's even possible), it's difficult to tell, because the marker doesn't give any feedback. When I try to compile all three .cpp files(g++ main.cpp A.cpp B.cpp) I get the following error messages:

- B.cpp:4:3: error: redefinition of ‘T B::getVal()’
  T B::getVal(){
- A.cpp:4:6: error: redefinition of ‘void A::print(B)’
  void A::print(B bInstance){

In my MRE the following needs to stay true:

- A and B must have a .h and .cpp file
- main.cpp may only include "A.h"
- A must require B for it to work

Here is my MRE:
-It makes an instance of B and then uses an instance of A to print a message with the value of instance B.

#### main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main(){
  B<char> b1;
  b1.val='B';
  A<char> a1;
  a1.print(b1);
}
```

#### A.h

```
#ifndef AAAA
#define AAAA

#include<iostream>
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class A{
public:
  void print(B<T> bInstance);
};

#include "A.cpp"

#endif
```

#### A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

template <class T>
void A<T>::print(B<T> bInstance){
  cout<<"I am A, and I am using "<<bInstance.getVal()<<endl;
}
```

#### B.h

```
#ifndef BBBB
#define BBBB

template <class T>
class B{
public:
  T val;
  T getVal();
};

#include "B.cpp"

#endif
```

#### B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

template <class T>
T B<T>::getVal(){
  return val;
}
```

#### Working compile and run commands

```
g++ main.cpp

./a.out
```

#### Commands it should work with(if possible)

```
g++ main.cpp A.cpp B.cpp

./a.out
```

Comment: I'm still new here and I've realized I use too many words to describe my problems. I tried to cut it down, but if this is still too much let me know.

Comment: Don't include cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

You should never `#include ".cpp"` in headers. Implementations of function  templates must be in headers, not in `cpp`. In your example, `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` are not needed at all. If they are still required by the task, make them empty except for `#include` directive.

Edit: If your automarker does not like it, you can also try inlining your implementations, e.g.

```
template <class T>
class B{
public:
  T val;
  T getVal(){
     return val;
  }
};
```

Comment: The automarker detects when you put the implementation in the header files instead of the.cpp files, so I'll still get zero, but thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it does so even for **template** implementations? If so, I'd say it is a bug in the marker.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I think there's a way to do it, but it's extremely difficult to know, because we don't know what the makefile looks like or what test code they run, or even what error that the compiler gives.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, with the files as they are right now, is that when you try to compile B.cpp, then this:

```
#include "B.h"

template <class T>
T B<T>::getVal(){
  return val;
}
```

and this:

```
#ifndef BBBB
#define BBBB

template <class T>
class B{
public:
  T val;
  T getVal();
};

#include "B.cpp"

#endif
```

combines into this:

```
#ifndef BBBB
#define BBBB

template <class T>
class B{
public:
  T val;
  T getVal();
};

#ifndef BBBB     // <- BBBB has been defined at this point, so everything between  this and the #endif is skipped
#endif

template <class T>
T B<T>::getVal(){
  return val;
}

#endif

template <class T>
T B<T>::getVal(){
  return val;
}
```

At this point I hope that it is obvious why you are getting the error: `B.cpp:4:3: error: redefinition of ‘T B::getVal()’ T B::getVal(){`.

The correct fix is to just put the entire template implementation in the header, and get rid of the `.cpp` file. But if that is not an option because of a messed up automarker, then try to add include-guards to the `.cpp` file. But be aware that this is bad practice all around (`.cpp` files should never be `#include`'ed, and should thus never need include-guards), so if any human sees your code then be prepared for a lot of questions and raised eyebrows.

BUT! The first step should probably be to try and talk to whoever gave you the task because something is wrong here; either with the automarker or with your understanding of how it works. A template class should *not* have a `.cpp` file (or it should be empty).

Comment: I agree it's bad practice to #include .cpp files. I talked to a subject admin and in this particular case we should #include .cpp files. I will talk to them, and see what they say. Thanks a lot for your time!